# ¿Cómo resolver un sistema de ecuaciones lineales en R con matriz NO cuadrada?

Tags: r

Necesito para el máster resolver el siguiente sistema, lo he intentado con `Solve()` pero no me deja por que la matriz es **NO CUADRADA**.

La matriz es la siguiente (sería la parte del sistema multiplicada por las incógnitas):

```
a1 <- rbind(c(-1,0.5,0,0),c(1,-1,0.5,0),c(0,0.5,-1,1),c(0,0,0.5,-1),c(1,1,1,1))
```

Y el vector al que está igualado el sistema sería:

```
b1 <- c(0,0,0,0,1)
```

Answer (score 2):

En tu caso estás tratando de resolver el siguiente sistema:

```
-a + b/2             = 0
 a - b   + c/2       = 0
     b/2 + -c  + d   = 0
         + c/2 - d   = 0
 a + b   +  c  + d   = 1
```

Si lo llevamos a una matriz:

```
> a1 <- rbind(c(-1,0.5,0,0),c(1,-1,0.5,0),c(0,0.5,-1,1),c(0,0,0.5,-1),c(1,1,1,1))
> a1
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]   -1  0.5  0.0    0
[2,]    1 -1.0  0.5    0
[3,]    0  0.5 -1.0    1
[4,]    0  0.0  0.5   -1
[5,]    1  1.0  1.0    1
```

Y el vector de igualación es:

```
> b1 <- c(0,0,0,0,1)
> b1
[1] 0 0 0 0 1
```

Para resolver este sistema, ya has confirmado que `solve()` no sirve ya que su funcionamiento esta restringido a matrices cuadradas. Lo que puedes usar es [`qr.solve()`](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/qr.html) de la siguiente manera:

```
> qr.solve(a1,b1)
[1] 0.1666667 0.3333333 0.3333333 0.1666667
```

O si prefieres ver el resultado como fracciones, puedes usar `as.fractions()` del paquete `MASS`:

```
> library(MASS) 
> as.fractions(qr.solve(a1,b1))
[1] 1/6 1/3 1/3 1/6
```